# undefined reference to and non-virtual thunk to

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I have such classes:

```
class Product
    {
        public :
            virtual double getPrice();
            virtual void setPrice(double price);
    };

class MusicProduct
    {
        protected:

            string author;
            double price;

        public :

            virtual string getAuthor();
            virtual void setAuthor(string author);
            ~MusicProduct();
    };

class CD : public MusicProduct, public Product
    {
        public :

            string getAuthor();
            void setAuthor(string author);
            double getPrice();
            void setPrice(double price);
    };

string CD::getAuthor()
    {
        return MusicProduct::author;
    }

    void CD::setAuthor(string author)
    {
        MusicProduct:author = author;
    }

    void setPrice(double price)
    {
    MusicProduct::price = price;
    }

    double getPrice()
    {
        return MusicProduct::price;
    }
```

And I have those errors:

```
/home/katie/Desktop/Temp/MusicStore.cpp||In member function ‘virtual bool  MusicStore::hasProduct( Product)’:|
/home/katie/Desktop/Temp/MusicStore.cpp|15|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|
/home/katie/Desktop/Temp/MusicStore.cpp||In member function ‘virtual  Product  MusicStore::getProduct( Product)’:|
/home/katie/Desktop/Temp/MusicStore.cpp|20|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|
/home/katie/Desktop/Temp/MusicStore.cpp||In member function ‘virtual bool  MusicStore::buyProduct( Product)’:|
/home/katie/Desktop/Temp/MusicStore.cpp|25|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|
/home/katie/Desktop/Temp/MusicStore.cpp||In member function ‘virtual bool  MusicStore::returnProduct( Product)’:|
/home/katie/Desktop/Temp/MusicStore.cpp|30|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|
/home/katie/Desktop/Temp/Store/CD.cpp||In member function ‘virtual void  CD::setAuthor(std::string)’:|
/home/katie/Desktop/Temp/Store/CD.cpp|12|warning: label ‘MusicProduct’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]|
obj/Debug/Store/CD.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5Music2CDE[vtable for  CD]+0x10)||undefined reference to ` CD::getPrice()'|
obj/Debug/Store/CD.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5Music2CDE[vtable for  CD]+0x14)||undefined reference to ` CD::setPrice(double)'|
obj/Debug/Store/CD.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5Music2CDE[vtable for  CD]+0x20)||undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to  CD::getPrice()'|
obj/Debug/Store/CD.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5Music2CDE[vtable for  CD]+0x24)||undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to  CD::setPrice(double)'|
obj/Debug/Store/CD.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5Music2CDE[typeinfo for  CD]+0x10)||undefined reference to `typeinfo for  MusicProduct'|
obj/Debug/Store/CD.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5Music2CDE[typeinfo for  CD]+0x18)||undefined reference to `typeinfo for  Product'|
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 5 warnings ===|
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 16):

Besides the missing CD:: qualifier error mentioned by momogentoo, this is another very sneaky error:

```
void CD::setAuthor(string author)
{
    MusicProduct:author = author; // <-- !!!
}
```

Since you used a single colon, it isn't interpreted as the resolution operator, but as a label (for gotos). What the statement will actually do is just self-assignment for the same string object (which for std::string will have no effect).

Comment: OK figured out all other errors but how to deal with error you mentioned?

Comment: @Katie Just change it into a double-colon: `MusicProduct::author = author;`

Comment: Just hit this error message. Never figured it out and it went away with a `make clean`, so I guess just stale object files.

Answer (score 2):

void setPrice(double price) -> void CD::setPrice(double price)

same for getPrice()

Answer (score 2):

First problem:

```
undefined reference to `CD::getPrice()'
```

Your definition of that function is missing the `CD::` qualification; so it instead declares and defines a non-member function.

```
double CD::getPrice()
{//    ^^^^ Add this
MusicProduct::price = price;
}
```

Likewise for `CD::setPrice`.

Second problem:

```
undefined reference to `typeinfo for  MusicProduct'
```

Presumably, `MusicProduct` is supposed to be an abstract class, and you don't want to provide definitions for its virtual functions. In that case, you must declare them *pure virtual*:

```
virtual double getPrice() = 0;
//                        ^^^ Add this
```

If it's not supposed to be abstract, then you'll need to implement those functions.

Third problem:

```
In member function ‘virtual bool  MusicStore::hasProduct( Product)’:
warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

Presumably, you have a function called `MusicStore::hasProduct` which is supposed to return a boolean, but doesn't.

Comment: if I implement methods from Product class as pure virtual, I wont be able to do this: `class MusicStore{ public: void addProduct(Product p);};` is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @Katie: If you want to use polymorphism at all, then you'll have to pass a reference (`Product & p`) or pointer (`Product * p`). Even if it weren't abstract, trying to copy it will almost certainly give incorrect behaviour due to the [slicing problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626); so it's better to leave the base class abstract and not try to copy objects.